# What is latest ruby on rails enterprise edition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `ruby 1.9.3` and `rails 3.2.6`. It is very slow in production. Is `ruby 1.8.7` the only enterprise edition? Is any other later enterprise edition of Ruby available?

Comment: Slowness can also be caused by app design, DB architecture, and a myriad other things. I recommend profiling the app using something like [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the last REE is based on 1.8.7.  The technical improvements made in 1.9 / 2.0 made it unnecessary to continue maintaining a separate 'Enterprise Edition' fork.  A brief explanation can be found [here](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/02/21/ruby-enterprise-edition-1-8-7-2012-02-released-end-of-life-imminent/) (see End of Life section).

If you are finding that 1.9.3 is slow, you can try patching with the back-ported GC improvements to 2.0 (along with some other modest improvements) - see [here](https://github.com/skaes/rvm-patchsets) for how you can do this.  However, all this assumes that the slowdown is due to ruby itself and not due to the code, architecture, or server overhead...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [website](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/) "Notice: Ruby Enterprise Edition has reached End of Life in 2012. The website is still up, and it still works, but it's no longer actively developed and it is no longer supported."

On the download page the current version listed is 1.8.7, since there it's end of life, it doesn't look like a new version will be appearing.